# Can an integrable discontinuous function have vertical asymtpotes?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals

This is a general question .

I was thinking, as integrable discointinuous functions are indeed improper integrals, which follow to be limits, that vertical asymptotes may exist.

However, i've seen people say it is is impossible whilst others say its possible. I'm pretty confused, any help would be greaT :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about improper integrals, there is no problem. Consider $f\colon(0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt x}$. Then\begin{align}\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_\varepsilon^1\frac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\left(2\sqrt1-2\sqrt\varepsilon\right)\\&=2.\end{align}

Comment: I really like the example! thank you ! integrable disconitnous functions are one of the three types of improper integrals. So with your example i could easily say that the statement is false, and that improper integrals  CAN indeed have vertical asymtpotes. correct?

Comment: That is correct.